# ERROR 303: Subindice (23) fuera de rango (1...22) en pseint

Tags: array, pseint

Ayuda estoy intentando hacer un arreglo para un algoritmo pero al momento de ejecutarlo siempre me dice el mismo error:

> ERROR 303: Subindice (23) fuera de rango (1...22)
> No se encontro descripción para este error

Ayuda por favor.

```
Algoritmo arreglo_siglo

    definir siglo, tamaño como real;
    escribir "ingrese tamaño"
    leer tamaño
    Dimension  arreglo[tamaño]
    siglo<- 1
    
    Repetir
        Para x<-6 Hasta 0 Con Paso -2 Hacer
            arreglo[siglo]<-x
            siglo=siglo+1
            
            Si x<-0 Entonces
                x<-6
            Fin Si
            
        Fin Para
    Hasta Que siglo=tamaño
    
    Escribir arreglo[1]

FinAlgoritmo
```

Lo que busco es guardar una serie de datos 6,4,2,0 por x cantidad de veces.

Comment: Revisa cómo se definen los arreglos en pseint. Es muy posible que los índices comiencen en cero, no en uno, así que la condición del `Hasta Que` posiblemente se esté saliendo del arreglo cuando `siglo=tamaño`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es el siguiente:
En cada iteración del ciclo `Repetir`, el ciclo `Para x<-6...` se ejecuta 4 veces `(6, 4, 2 y 0)`.
Esto significa que cuando el ciclo `Para` termina, la variable `siglo` incrementó 4 unidades.

Si defines un arreglo de 22 posiciones, en la quita iteración del ciclo `Repetir` la variable `siglo` tendría los valores `21, 22, 23 y 24` provocando el error en el `23` porque el arreglo tiene sólo 22 posiciones.

Una solución sería validar que la variable `siglo` sea menor o igual al `tamaño` del arreglo antes de intentar asignarle valor.

Por otra parte, la condición para terminar el ciclo `Repetir` debería ser `Hasta que siglo sea mayor o igual que tamaño` porque si lo dejas como está el programa no terminaría nunca en la mayoría de los casos.

Con estos cambios el código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
Algoritmo arreglo_siglo

    definir siglo, tamaño como real;
    escribir "ingrese tamaño"
    leer tamaño
    Dimension  arreglo[tamaño]
    siglo<- 1
    
    Repetir
        Para x<-6 Hasta 0 Con Paso -2 Hacer
         // | Agrega esta condición
         // V
            Si siglo <= tamaño Entonces
                arreglo[siglo]<-x
            FinSi
            siglo=siglo+1
            
         // | Esta condición como esta planteada nunca se cumple
         // V
            Si x<-0 Entonces
                x<-6
            Fin Si      
        Fin Para
        //         | Cambia la condición por mayor o igual
        //         V
    Hasta Que siglo>=tamaño
    
    Escribir arreglo[1]

FinAlgoritmo
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si al cambiar la condicion el algoritmo se ejecuta, pero ahora segun el comentario que me dejaste, la condicion si <-0 entonces x<- 6 como puedo hacer que se ejecute para que se reinicie el ciclo desde 6

Comment: Esa condicion no es necesaria porque una vez que el ciclo `Para` termina, el ciclo `Repetir` se encarga de reiniciarlo.

Comment: si muchas gracias cuando lo quite funciono perfecto

Comment: Un gusto ayudar, considera marcar mi respuesta como aceptada.