# No se que debo cambiar para solucionar un error en PSeInt

Tags: array, pseint

tengo este codigo en PSeInt pero a la hora de ejecutarlo me sale este error:

> Lin 9 (inst 1): ERROR 303: Subindice (0) fuera de rango (1...8).

No se que debo cambiarle, para que se ejecute correctamente o si directamente es algún error de configuración de la app, me ayudarían mucho.

```
Algoritmo Ejercicio5
    Dimension numeros[8]
    Dimension repeticiones[4]
    Definir i, j, numeros, repeticiones Como Enteros
    i <- 0
    j <- 0   
    Mientras i < 8 Hacer
        Mostrar "Ingrese un número entre 3 y 6:"
        Leer numeros[i]
        
        // Asegúrate de que el número esté en el rango correcto antes de incrementar i
        Si numeros[i] >= 3 Y numeros[i] <= 6 Entonces
            i <- i + 1
        FinSi
    FinMientras
    
    Para j <- 0 Hasta 3 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        repeticiones[j] <- 0
    FinPara
    
    // Reiniciamos i para recorrer el array numeros nuevamente
    i <- 0
    Para i <- 0 Hasta 7 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        // Asegúrate de que el número esté en el rango correcto
        Si numeros[i] >= 3 Y numeros[i] <= 6 Entonces
            repeticiones[numeros[i] - 3] <- repeticiones[numeros[i] - 3] + 1
        FinSi
    FinPara
    
    Mostrar "Listado de números ingresados:"
    Para i <- 0 Hasta 7 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        // Asegúrate de que el número esté en el rango correcto antes de mostrarlo
        Si numeros[i] >= 3 Y numeros[i] <= 6 Entonces
            Mostrar numeros[i]
        FinSi
    FinPara
    
    Mostrar "Cantidad de veces que se repitió cada número:"
    Para j <- 0 Hasta 3 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Mostrar "Número ", j + 3, ": ", repeticiones[j]
    FinPara
    
    Mostrar "Valor de cada número elevado a la cantidad de veces que se repitió:"
    Para i <- 0 Hasta 7 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        // Asegúrate de que el número esté en el rango correcto antes de mostrarlo
        Si numeros[i] >= 3 Y numeros[i] <= 6 Entonces
            Mostrar "Número ", numeros[i], " elevado a ", repeticiones[numeros[i] - 3], ": ", numeros[i] ^ repeticiones[numeros[i] - 3]
        FinSi
    FinPara
FinAlgoritmo
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [ERROR 303: Subindice (23) fuera de rango (1...22) en pseint](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/441926/error-303-subindice-23-fuera-de-rango-1-22-en-pseint)

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que PSeInt es configurable.
Dentro de estas configuraciones está la posibilidad de definir si lo arreglos y los índices de las cadenas empiezan en 0 o en 1. No especificaste que perfil estás usando, pero posiblemente estés usando una configuración o perfil que tome los arreglos en base 1 y por lo que veo en el código se está considerando que los arreglos tienen índice 0 a n-1
O bien cambias los recorridos de 1 hasta n o utiliza un perfil que considere los arreglos en base 0.